# Assigning a Result set to another Result Set reference variable

Tags: java, resultset

I am calling a method which returns a result set to a servlet class. Inside the servlet class I am assigning it to another result set variable. but I am getting Compile error as

> "Type mismatch: cannot convert from java.sql.ResultSet to
>   javax.resource.cci.ResultSet"

Below is what I am trying to do:

```
ResultSet rs1=null;
ContactDAO cdo = new ContactDAO();
try{
    rs1 = cdo.viewContact(emailId);
    while (rs1.next()) {
        ContactVO cnt = new ContactVO ();
        cnt.setEmailId(rs1.getString("emailId"));
        cnt.setFName(rs1.getString("FName"));
        cnt.setGroupId(rs1.getString("GroupId"));
        ...
```

and this is the method signature that I am calling, this method returns a ResultSet rs:

```
public ResultSet viewContact(String emailId)...
```

Comment: check import statements in both java files. Resultset import should be same in both java files.

Comment: Please [edit] your question and make the Java code readable.

Comment: @Tichodroma I suggested an edit improving the code formatting.

Answer (score 0):

A formatter could make your code alot more readable but from what I understand you are just importing the wrong package. If you find it too difficult to find out which import gives you the ResultSet you can simply use the fully qualified pathname to initiate your ResultSet like this:

`java.sql.ResultSet rs1 = null`

EDIT:
After the format i noticed that it was the other way around!